# The styles in the recent posts widgets plugin not working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, recent-posts

I am trying to add a wordpress recent posts widget plugin in a theme
but somehow even after adding the same class the styles ae not reflecting in the front end
i tried to enqueue style in the plugin but that too didnt help

here is the plugin code

```
<?php echo $args[ 'before_widget' ]; ?>

<div id="rpwwt-<?php echo $args[ 'widget_id' ];?>" class="mb-50 mb-sm-30">
    <?php if ( $title ) echo $args[ 'before_title' ] . $title . $args[ 'after_title' ]; ?>
    
    <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) { $r->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="sided-90x mb-30">
          <div class="s-left">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<?php echo $this->customs[ 'link_target' ]; ?>><?php 
            if ( $bools[ 'show_thumb' ] ) {
                $is_thumb = false;
                // if always only the default image
                if ( $bools[ 'use_default_only' ] ) {
                    echo $default_img;
                // if only first image
                } elseif ( $bools[ 'only_1st_img' ] ) {
                    // try to find and to display the first post image and to return success
                    $is_thumb = $this->the_first_post_image();
                } else {
                    // look for featured image
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        // if there is featured image then show it
                        the_post_thumbnail( $this->customs[ 'thumb_dimensions' ] );
                        $is_thumb = true;
                    } else {
                        // if user wishes first image trial
                        if ( $bools[ 'try_1st_img' ] ) {
                            // try to find and to display the first post image and to return success
                            $is_thumb = $this->the_first_post_image();
                        } // if try_1st_img 
                    } // if has_post_thumbnail
                } // if only_1st_img
                // if there is no image 
                if ( ! $is_thumb ) {
                    // if user allows default image then
                    if ( $bools[ 'use_default' ] ) {
                        echo $default_img;
                    } // if use_default
                } // if not is_thumb
                // (else do nothing)
            } // if show_thumb ?>
            </a></div>
            <div class="s-right left-text">
            <?php
            if ( $bools[ 'show_categories' ] ) {
                ?><h6 class="color-semi-black"><?php echo $this->get_the_categories( $r->post->ID ); ?></h6><?php 
            }
            // show title if wished
            if ( ! $bools[ 'hide_title' ] ) {
                ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h6 class="font-11 mtb-5"><?php if ( $post_title = $this->get_the_trimmed_post_title() ) { echo $post_title; } else { the_ID(); } ?></h6></a><?php
            }
            ?><?php 
            
            if ( $bools[ 'show_date' ] ) {
                ?><h6 class="color-primary"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h6><?php 
            }
        ?>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php } // while() ?>
    
</div><!-- .rpwwt-widget -->
<?php echo $args[ 'after_widget' ]; ?>
```

here is the output

```
<div id="news-side">
<div id="rpwwt-recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-2" class="mb-50 mb-sm-30">
    <h5 class="mb-30 left-text">Recent Posts</h5>   
            <div class="sided-90x mb-30">
          <div class="s-left">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/the-secret-of-the-perfect-italian-pizza/" target="_blank"><img width="90" height="90" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/blog-2-1000x400-1-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-90x90 size-90x90 wp-post-image" alt="" />           </a></div>
            <div class="s-right left-text">
            <h6 class="color-semi-black">Recipes</h6><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/the-secret-of-the-perfect-italian-pizza/"><h6 class="font-11 mtb-5">The secret of the perfect italian pizza</h6></a><h6 class="color-primary">2020-06-15</h6>        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="sided-90x mb-30">
          <div class="s-left">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/paneer-pizza/" target="_blank"><img width="90" height="90" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/blog-1-1000x400-1-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-90x90 size-90x90 wp-post-image" alt="" />          </a></div>
            <div class="s-right left-text">
            <h6 class="color-semi-black">Recipes</h6><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/paneer-pizza/"><h6 class="font-11 mtb-5">Paneer Pizza</h6></a><h6 class="color-primary">2020-06-15</h6>          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="sided-90x mb-30">
          <div class="s-left">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/recipe-of-the-week-tomato-pastas/" target="_blank"><img width="90" height="90" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/blog-3-1000x400-1-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-90x90 size-90x90 wp-post-image" alt="" />          </a></div>
            <div class="s-right left-text">
            <h6 class="color-semi-black">Recipes</h6><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/recipe-of-the-week-tomato-pastas/"><h6 class="font-11 mtb-5">Recipe of the week: Tomato pastas</h6></a><h6 class="color-primary">2020-06-15</h6>         </div>
        </div>
        
</div><!-- .rpwwt-widget -->
</div>
```

i tried to enque style like this but that too didnt help

```
<?php echo $args[ 'before_widget' ]; ?>
<?php //add styles
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','rpwwt_styles');
function rpwwt_styles(){
  
  wp_register_style('custom',plugins_url('css/custom.css',__FILE__));
  wp_enqueue_style('custom');
   
}?>
<div id="rpwwt-<?php echo $args[ 'widget_id' ];?>" class="mb-50 mb-sm-30">
    <?php if ( $title ) echo $args[ 'before_title' ] . $title . $args[ 'after_title' ]; ?>
    
    <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) { $r->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="sided-90x mb-30">
          <div class="s-left">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<?php echo $this->customs[ 'link_target' ]; ?>><?php 
            if ( $bools[ 'show_thumb' ] ) {
                $is_thumb = false;
                // if always only the default image
                if ( $bools[ 'use_default_only' ] ) {
                    echo $default_img;
                // if only first image
                } elseif ( $bools[ 'only_1st_img' ] ) {
                    // try to find and to display the first post image and to return success
                    $is_thumb = $this->the_first_post_image();
                } else {
                    // look for featured image
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        // if there is featured image then show it
                        the_post_thumbnail( $this->customs[ 'thumb_dimensions' ] );
                        $is_thumb = true;
                    } else {
                        // if user wishes first image trial
                        if ( $bools[ 'try_1st_img' ] ) {
                            // try to find and to display the first post image and to return success
                            $is_thumb = $this->the_first_post_image();
                        } // if try_1st_img 
                    } // if has_post_thumbnail
                } // if only_1st_img
                // if there is no image 
                if ( ! $is_thumb ) {
                    // if user allows default image then
                    if ( $bools[ 'use_default' ] ) {
                        echo $default_img;
                    } // if use_default
                } // if not is_thumb
                // (else do nothing)
            } // if show_thumb ?>
            </a></div>
            <div class="s-right left-text">
            <?php
            if ( $bools[ 'show_categories' ] ) {
                ?><h6 class="color-semi-black"><?php echo $this->get_the_categories( $r->post->ID ); ?></h6><?php 
            }
            // show title if wished
            if ( ! $bools[ 'hide_title' ] ) {
                ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h6 class="font-11 mtb-5"><?php if ( $post_title = $this->get_the_trimmed_post_title() ) { echo $post_title; } else { the_ID(); } ?></h6></a><?php
            }
            ?><?php 
            
            if ( $bools[ 'show_date' ] ) {
                ?><h6 class="color-primary"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h6><?php 
            }
        ?>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php } // while() ?>
    
</div><!-- .rpwwt-widget -->
<?php echo $args[ 'after_widget' ]; ?>
```

check screenshots for reference
[image: what i get]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed

the proble was in the custom.css

where i added

```
.s-right{
    margin-top:-30px;
}
```

i removed that and that fixed the margin issue